# how to get the information in body into the global scoop from request.get

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im totally new to JavaScript and I have a problem.

This is my code and it is working

```
'use strict';

const request = require("request")
const url = "https://something/v1/"

request.get(
  `${url}/tickers?symbols=tBTCUSD`,
    (error, response, body) => console.log(body)
    )
```

So this writes the expected data on the screen.
So I have the data, I just dont want to put it on my screen, I want to process it.
But how do I get that data out from the request.get function?

Something like this

```
'use strict';

const request = require("request")
const url = "https://something/v1/"

let global_answer

request.get(
  `${url}/tickers?symbols=tBTCUSD`,
    (error, response, body) => {
        console.log(body)
        global_answer = body;
})

my_function(global_answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable in the global scope like this:

```
var debugBody;

request.get(
    `${url}/tickers?symbols=tBTCUSD`,
    (error, response, body) => {
        debugBody = body;
        console.log(body)
});

console.log(debugBody);
```

**EDIT: Async function**

This won't work because request.get works asynchronously, if you want to call a function, you should have the function defined globally and call it from inside the request.get callback:

```
var debugBody;

function logRequestBody(body){
    console.log(body);
}

request.get(
    `${url}/tickers?symbols=tBTCUSD`,
    (error, response, body) => {
        logRequestBody(body);
});
```

The code will work that way.

Comment: In your example `debugBody` will be `undefined` _always_, because `request.get` is async function.

Comment: But this is exactly the way I have written in my section where I expain how I want to do, this doesnt work

Comment: Oh thanks, i didn't notice it. Will upload a working one

Comment: @Megadavve what is your point on having the variable in the global scope if the function is asyncronous? You should use a callback and use the variable inside the callback.

Comment: Hi, It does work. But seems very complicated to get data returned from a request compared to C and C++

Comment: If the answer was useful for you, I would appreciate if you mark the answer as correct. ;)

Answer (score 0):

something more like this:

```
'use strict';

const request = require("request");
const url = "${url}/tickers?symbols=tBTCUSD";

request.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
  console.log(body);
  my_function(body);
});
```